# Python won't run a basic fibonacci function

Tags: python

I'm new to python and can't figure out what the problem with simple fibonacci function is. It also calculates amount of iterations the function makes.

Here is the code:

```
times = 0;

def fib(n):
    times = times + 1
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

When I run it, for some reason I get this error:

```
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

  File "fibo.py", line 7
    if n == 0:
             ^
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have mixed tabs and spaces, this is evil in python ;) You have to choose, tabs or spaces.

The code you post seems to work, except the `times = times + 1` that complains about `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'times' referenced before assignment`, normal as times is a global variable and should be treated as well :

```
global times
times = times + 1
```

Comment: So if I want to access a global variable from every function, I should always go through these 2 lines??? I mean, it's the worst type of redundancy. Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: @NoobDev4iPhone : in a general way, global variables are not a good choice. To completely avoid that, you could pass it as parameter, or create an object holding the global data...

Comment: @NoobDev4iPhone, you only need to use `global` if you want to rebind the reference. If you are just using the value of the variable Python will look in the global namespace when it doesn't find it in the local namespace

Answer (score 1):

You have a tab character on that line.  Use spaces for indentation as recommended by [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (the official python style guide).

> Tabs or Spaces?
>
> Never mix tabs and spaces.
>
> The most popular way of indenting Python is with spaces only.  The
>   second-most popular way is with tabs only.  Code indented with a
>   mixture of tabs and spaces should be converted to using spaces
>   exclusively.  When invoking the Python command line interpreter with
>   the -t option, it issues warnings about code that illegally mixes tabs
>   and spaces.  When using -tt these warnings become errors.  These
>   options are highly recommended!
>
> For new projects, spaces-only are strongly recommended over tabs. 
>   Most editors have features that make this easy to do.

Comment: Certainly my least favorite part of python. I understand that tabs don't always mean a consistent number of spaces, but it just blows unless you have an editor with soft tabs

Comment: @chris:  Funny, the need to mentally parse brackets while ignoring indentation is my least favorite part of other languages.

Comment: @Chris to me, tabs not meaning a consistent number of spaces is exactly what's good about them: people get to view the code with the amount of indentation they prefer. I have always been a proponent of the tab-only style. That said, what sane editor lacks soft tabs, in 2011?